# Compare an string with an array in query sql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I tried to create a query in symfony but no results. So I have an array call $aFilter['aColors'] :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

In my database for table Product I have an field call product_colors who is a string : 1,2,3

Now I want to compare the array with this string, I tried like this :

```
      if(isset($aFilter['aColors'])){
            $aColors = implode("','",$aFilter['aColors']);
            $qb->andWhere('p.product_colors IN (:colors)')
                ->setParameter('colors', $aColors);
        }
```

But not working.Help me please. Thx in advance.

Exist a solution foor this problem?

Comment: You need to create an individual bind placeholder for each individual entry in the array, and bind the individual array elements (not a string).... that's simply how bind vars work

Comment: If your stored data is a string, you cannot use IN statement, and expecting MySQL to guess what to do with... The simplest thing to do here is to perform a combination of multiple `LIKE %,<color>,%` in your column, but it's dirty

Answer (score 0):

Replace

$aColors = implode("','",$aFilter['aColors']);

To

$aColors = implode(",",$aFilter['aColors']);